# How to run received JavaScript from the client side(html, js)?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

I'm using a JS promised based library (axios) to get a response from backend which returns a complete JS file. Once I receive this file how do I actually use it in my current page?

this the code:

```
axios.get('/foobar')
     .then(jsFile => {
          //use jsFile on current webpage       
      })
```

I have read some answers using `eval()`, but I would prefer to avoid this method. Anyone has an idea how to proceed?

Comment: `jsFile` is a script text?

Comment: What is the content of `jsFile`?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes it is when I console.log it I see printed in console all the text within the js file

Comment: Why are you using axios instead of `<script>` in the first place?

Comment: What is wrong with `eval` that isn't wrong with injectecting the script though other mechanisms?

Comment: @Quentin because it's a progressive app, I need to load this script only when user clicks on X button

Comment: Do you also execute some method after loading the script?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I can execute whatever I need inside the  then method axios.get().then(()=>{})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `script` tag with contents as `jsFile`

```
function addScriptToSession( jsFile )
{
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jsFile));
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = jsFile;
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
}
```

Use it as

```
  axios.get('/foobar')
 .then(jsFile => {
      addScriptToSession(jsFile)     
  })
```

Comment: Cool but how is this any different than `eval`..?

Comment: @Redu with eval you can't use properly the debugger. Every call to eval() produces a new instance of the JS interpreter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea